# Return an array containing the first n Fibonacci numbers using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, fibonacci

I'm still a beginner when it comes to pointers and memory allocation, and I'm trying to create a function that returns the first n numbers of the Fibonacci sequence using pointers. When I try using this code, it returns random numbers but I don't know how I would fix it. Here's the code:

```
int* generateFibonacci(int n)
{
// make an array for n ints
int *result = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

if (result == NULL)
{
    // fail
    printf("I have no memory, sorry. Exiting");
    exit(1);
}

result[0] = 0;
result[1] = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    result[i + 2] = result[i - 1] + result[i - 2];
}

return result;
}
```

If someone could point me to the right direction that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing array out of bounds in the `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    result[i + 2] = result[i - 1] + result[i - 2];
}
```

For `i = 0`, `i -1` and `i -2` is out of bound access. Similarly, for `= n-2`, `i+2` is accessing `result[n]` which is also out of bound access (array indexing goes from 0 to n-1).
You can fix this by

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    result[i] = result[i - 2] + result[i - 1];
}
```